# StartCoRoutine(string) NOT implementing desired effect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a mild understanding of the exact functionality of Coroutine so I decided to create a project with it. Best way to learn, no? Anyway, I have working script for UI at the start of every level it tells you what level and/or if it's a new checkpoint (spawn zones). It also tells the player how much health and lives are left. My current problem here is that the WaitForSeconds() doesn't pause the "Checkpoint" text, so it goes straight into the GUI funtion and seemingly skips the checkpoint(Cpoint() ) function. However, through debug log, I know for fact it doesn't. The change occurs so fast upon start up that it's gone before read.

I have the coroutines commented out because it runs nonstop. I only want this code to function when the collider is contacted.

All explainations are welcomed! I'm here to learn! Also, if anyone can point me in the right direction as how to approach this, I'd be very appreciative!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class txtLvl1 : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization

public Text checkpointTxt;


void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    Cpoint();
    StartCoroutine("Wait1");
    GUI();

}

void GUI()
{
    Debug.Log("GUI works");
   // StartCoroutine("Wait1");
    checkpointTxt.fontSize = 12;
    checkpointTxt.text = "Lives = " + HpSc.life + "\nHealth = " + HpSc.HP;


}



IEnumerator Wait() {

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

}

IEnumerator Wait1()
{

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

}

void Cpoint(){

    checkpointTxt.text = "( Checkpoint )";
    checkpointTxt.fontSize = 21;
   // StartCoroutine("Wait1");
    Debug.Log("Cpoint");
    //GUI();

}
```

Comment: [StartCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) takes an `IEnumerator` as a parameter. `StartCoroutine(Wait1)` <- no quotes around the function name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coroutines run asychronously from the caller.  When you call `StartCoroutine`, your calling function starts the coroutine and the continues executing.  So when you do

```
void MyFunction()
{
   Debug.Log("1");
   StartCoroutine(Wait());
   Debug.Log("2");        
}
```

Your program is going to print `1`, start the coroutine, and then print `2`, all within the same frame update of your game.  Your coroutine will continue executing on each subsequent frame update until it's done, but it's completely separate from `MyFunction` at this point.  This is the desired behavior, because imagine if Unity waited for your coroutine to end before moving on to the next line of code.  If that happened from within a `Start` or an `Update` method, now your entire game is hung and waiting for the coroutine to finish before anything else can happen.

If you want to print something, wait, then print something else and show a GUI, do that all from within the coroutine.

```
void Start()
{
   StartCoroutine(PrintAndWait());
}

IEnumerator PrintAndWait()
{
   Debug.Log("1");
   yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
   Debug.Log("2");
   ShowGui();
}
```

One more thing; the reason that your coroutine appears to run nonstop is because you're actually starting a new one every update frame.  That's not what you want, since you'll have dozens of instances of the coroutine running all the time.  Starting a coroutine doesn't stop any currently running coroutines.

You can accomplish what you want by starting your coroutine from within an [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) method.  Make sure you attach `Collider` components and `RigidBody` components appropriately as specified in the documentation.